# sscanf writing to variable issue

Tags: c++, c, scanf

i have a code like this

```
sprintf(data, "%d|Hello world|Ticket|Offset=44|msgId=1050        %d|%d|%d", r+1,header->m_msgId,header->m_sequence,header->m_offset);
```

where data is a char array of size 100 and header is a structure variable.

now after writing this whole to data using sprintf i want to break this whole data into two and then copy it into two new variable

```
char var1[100],var2[100];
```

This can be done with sscanf but waht i want is that in var1 i want only the part till

```
%d|Hello world|Ticket|Offset=44|msgId=1050
```

whereas in var2 i want the part after that ie

```
%d|%d|%d
```

.one way is to do %[^\t} and so on but in this case the value inside var1 is correct but inside var2 tab space is also inserted along with some weird character at the end of three %d.i cant change the format of data that has to be entered in my variable **data**.
please help me out that how can i do this using help of sscanf.thanks for any help in advance

Comment: What separates the `1050` and the `%d|%d|%d`? Must `sscanf()` be used?

Comment: post the sscanf() stmts. you are using.

Comment: @hmjd ya sscanf is must and __tab__ separates it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will provide the behaviour required:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char arr[] = "18|Hello world|Ticket|Offset=44|msgId=1050\t12|4|5";
    char var1[100];
    char var2[100];

    if (2 == sscanf(arr, "%[^\t]%s", var1, var2))
    {
        printf("var1[%s]\nvar2[%s]\n", var1, var2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See http://ideone.com/j8am8 for demo.

Comment: the two fields are not separated by \t but by spaces !

Comment: @A.G., see OP's comment below question where he states _tab separates it_.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
char data[]="%d|Hello world|Ticket|Offset=44|msgId=1050        %d|%d|%d";
char var1[100], var2[100];
char *szField1, *szField2;

// extract var1
szField1 = strstr(data, "  " );
memset( var1, 0, sizeof( var1 ) );
strncpy( var1, data, szField1 - data );

// extract var2
szField2 = strstr( szField1, "%" );
memset( var2, 0, sizeof( var2 ) );
strcpy( var2, szField2 );
```

Comment: @Mcolorz at least 2 spaces otherwise strstr will stop at " world|..."